# How to return a directory structure as a complete tree?

Tags: go

I have a directory structure like this:

```
reports
├── bar
│   └── 2021-01-25
└── foo
    └── 2021-01-25
```

I am new to go and try to use the Walk function,

Now I have this code

```
func FilePathWalkDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            if info.IsDir() && info.Name() == "pages" || info.Name() == "data" || info.Name() == "logs" {
                return filepath.SkipDir
            }
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}
```

And using this like:

```
func serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    lines := []string{}
    files, err := FilePathWalkDir("reports/")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        lines = append(lines, file)
    }

    output, err := json.Marshal(lines)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    //fmt.Println(string(jsonData))
    fmt.Fprintf(w, string(output))
}
```

And I get this

```json
"reports/"
"reports/bar"
"reports/bar/2021-01-25"
"reports/foo"
"reports/foo/2021-01-25"
```

But want this:

```json
"reports/bar/2021-01-25"
"reports/foo/2021-01-25"
```

But I only want to return the last bit (reports/foo/2021-01-27) for each directory - with the dates, and it could be many different dates, like it could be many different project names (foo, bar, barfoo, foobar etc).

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you please repaste the json as an extra code block? if you begin it with ```json it will highlight correctly.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.  Do you have a specific rule for what paths you want to return?  If so, are you having trouble writing this rule into Go code?

Comment: Just do not append the paths you do not want in your output to `lines`. Your question has _absolutely_ _nothing_ to do with JSON.

Comment: Had added some output example to try to clearify my question.

Comment: It seems you want to skip directories. Just test if a file is a directory before outputting it.

Comment: I think my issue is with append - I do not want to skip reading bar or foo - because what I want is the whole path to reports/foo/2021-01-25.

Comment: Changed subject to something more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want paths with dates, why not check to see if the suffix matches that pattern using Regex before appending?